# How to use frame layout in android

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-framelayout

i have to create an android layout which has a `textview` on the top, an `imageview` under that `textview` and a `imagebutton` under `imageview`.

When `imagebutton` is touched, the `textview` and `imageview` have to become invisible and a custom view must become visibile in the place where `textview` and `imageview` was.

If i use `linearlayout`, i have to use margintop whit negative values, but i think is not very useful cause on different screen size it will shown very bad. I think i have to use `framelayout` but i don't know how to do, can anyone explain me well how it work pls?

thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way than LinearLayout is using RelativeLayout. Give the same attributes to the overlaying components and do not set the relative attributes like layoutabove or layoutbelow.

Answer (score 3):

Why you want to take an FrameLayout? do it inside your LinearLayout. When imageButton is touched set text and imageView like this :

```
imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

and your customView to View.Visible.

I guess you came to negative margins, because you tried something like View.Invisible.
You can refer to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29), to see, what each state does.

Comment: In this way i can't put views one on other and show one instead other

Comment: Shure, you can. If you want to handle 2 or more Views as they were one, wrap them into another LinearLayout. You can hide some Views from the beginning, to switch to them, when they have to appear